# How to move a object in straight line in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

First, I calculated the Euclidean distance then I tried to iterated using loop to go to certain point using slope but the moving path doesn't like a straight line. Please help me to slove.

```
def move(roborect,grad):
   power=(x_cord[0]-roborect.x)**2+(y_cord[0]-roborect.y)**2
     distance=math.sqrt(power)
     if(distance>15):
        roborect.y=int(grad*roborect.x)+roborect.y
        roborect.x=roborect.x+5
        print(distance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the direction vector from the object to the target. Normalize the direction vector ([Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)). Scale the vector to a certain length and add the vector to the position:

```py
dx = x_cord[0]-roborect.x
dy = y_cord[0]-roborect.y
distance = math.sqrt(dx*dy + dy*dy)
if distance > 15:
    vx = dx * 5 / distance 
    vy = dy * 5 / distance 
    roborect.x += vx
    roborect.x += vy
```